# Hangouts chat - Change message background color based on hashtag

Tags: google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I want to change the background colour of the message based on the hashtag mentioned.

For example:

```
Red for #high
Green for #medium
Yellow for #low
```

Can it be done using Hangouts API?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this.

As you can see in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/cards), there is no way to change the background color of a message, even from a Card message. At most, you can format text via [this list of HTML tags](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards#card_text_formatting). But as you can see, this does not include `background color`. You could also add an [image](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/cards#image) with the color you desire, but it wouldn't be a `background color` either (it would take its own space and would not occupy all card message as a background).

If you think this would be an interesting functionality, you can submit a new feature request in Issue Tracker, using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=350158&template=1047215). Just make sure this request has not been made before by looking through [this list of issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:350158).